# Changing mailman list keywords for joining/leaving a mailing list

Tags: mailman

I am using mailman 3. Is it possible to change the keyword extensions for the purpose of mailing list management? For instance, is it be possible to change `list-join@DOMAIN` for `list-inscription@DOMAIN`, or `list-unsubscribe@DOMAIN` for `list-leave@DOMAIN`? Such flexibility would be useful for localization/language requirements.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.